# how to make Universal application, if i have mistakenly deleted MainStoryboard_iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, storyboard, ios-universal-app

I made iOS application first as universal , then some how i deleted MainStoryBoard_iPad because the client said that application required is only for iphone not for ipad. Now client asked me that he wants to run the same app on iPad with 2x button at the right bottom of the screen. Now when i run on iPad it crashes. What are the possible solutions to run the application smoothly on iPad.

Comment: did you recreate the MainStoryBoard_iPad ?

Comment: then you should add the file again to your project as a new resource again: `File` -> `New...` -> `File` | `User Interface` -> `View`. and _violá_, you've done! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your client want the app to run on the iPad with a 2x button, they do *not* want a universal app; they want an iPhone app.

You do this in your project properties. Switch the type from "Universal" to "iPhone". You'll probably also want to remove some of the extra lines in the Info.plist that refer to the iPad version.

Answer (score 0):

1) Even when you're the only person doing the development, always, **ALWAYS** use source control.

2) Go to your target, **Summary** tab, change the **Devices** to **Universal**, XCode should if you want to generate the iPad files - then modify the new files to fit your needs.